# ASP.NET MVC server path is different from application path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, relative-url

I have an unusual circumstance where our web server inserts a folder into the url path before loading the page. Let me give you an example:

The app is called equipment and if I were to run it on a normal server setup, it would look like:

www.site.com\equipment\home\index

BUT when I run it on our server, it inserts "idn" in the url:

www.site.com\idn\equipment\home\index

The messes up my relative references. The MVC functions want to redirect to use "\equipment\" instead of "\idn\equipment\".  This happens with Scripts.Render(), Return View(), etc.

Also, I can't hardcode the "idn" into my urls b/c then it is no longer relative and it won't work on my dev box or test servers b/c they don't have a "idn" subfolder in localhost.

I also tried functions such as Request.ApplicationPath and what not but none of them return the "idn" in the result.

Is there way to MVC to know that this "idn" was inserted into the url and account for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create your application on the test/production server in the idn folder, then it all works.

Comment: I should say it all works if you use app-relative (start with `~` or relative URLs (start with `.`,`..` or a file/folder name).  Absolute URLs (the ones that start with `/`) won't work, but you shouldn't be using them anyhow.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I need to know if there is a built in function that will recognize when the 'idn' is in the url and redirect accordingly. Hard-coding paths on different computers isn't possible. The app-relative "~" doesn't return the "idn". It returns "/equipment".

Comment: You don't have to hard code different paths on different computers if you do it like I said.  It's how you set up the application on IIS that is causing you the problem.

Comment: How do you mean 'how I set up the application'? Is there a configuration setting I can do so that it knows about the 'idn' in the url?

Comment: When you publish your application to your test server, do you have idn set up as an application or is it just a regular folder? It sounds like you have the later when you want the former.

Comment: On the production server, "idn" is the site name (under IIS), and "equipment" is the application name. The server admin configured it so that you have to use "idn" in the url to access the site. The powers that be decided this is the way it should be. So I have to figure out how to create relative urls that know "idn" is in the url.

Comment: For example, on my local system, I have my MVC application set up so that localhost:80/Home/Index works, and on our staging server it is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/sitename/Home/Index, and on production it is xxx.com/Home/Index and we don't change anything in the code regarding paths.

Comment: Good example. Following that, here is how my scenario is setup:
dev: localhost:80/Home/Index
test: www.dev.com/equipment/Home/Index
production: wwww.production.com/idn/equipment/Home/Index

Thus, every url has a different "application path" (if that is the proper term) from each other. I need a funtion that will return "/idn/equipment/" and the production server.

Comment: Put the equipment application in a folder named idn in your site named idn, then all your app relative URLs will translate to `sitename/idn/equipment/`

Comment: Or more simply put `The app-relative "~" doesn't return the "idn"` means you have not configured your server correctly.  The app-relative "~" should be returning the "idn".

Comment: Going back to your original post, `www.site.com\idn\equipment\home\index`, `www.site.com` is your site (or should be).  `idn` is a folder under that site, and `equipment` is an application in the idn folder.